# Access id denied whenever trying to access contents in Iframe in same domain

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, iframe, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm using IE 11 and I have an HTMl window with an IFrame being loaded with a Sharepoint application. Both the HTML and the contents being loaded into the iframe are from the same domain but I'm still having issues related to accessing the contents found inside the iframe. Whenever I navigate into a folder in sharepoint I find myself accessing the iframe *contentWindow* and having basically all the properties with *Access is Denied*, including document and location. Should there be something specific I'm missing? Maybe from sharepoint perspective (permissions, authentication) or server configuration?

Comment: Might be potentially related to the IE settings, have you tried adding the SP site to the trusted sites, or running in compatibility mode in internet explorer?

Comment: I've tried using the Trusted Sites and the Intranet Zone and nothing works. I didn't have compatibility mode running but tested it and it still behaves the same. Thanks for the idea though, hadn't thought about compatiblity.

Comment: What version of Sharepoint are you using? Are you using CRM 2011 Online or On premise? I have heard that it could also have to do with IE attempting to protect against server side scripting. Have you tried the combination of ~ Trusted Sites > Intranet Zone > and Allow script-initiated windows without size or position constraints (in security settings)? Also have you tried this in any other browser?